# SQL Server Rolling Percentage Help based on Condition

Tags: sql-server

I have this query in a temp table 
and i need help guys

```
Create Table ##TBL (ID INT, NOs INT,PersonCount INT)
INSERT INTO ##TBL VALUES
(0,0,36),
(0,0,10),
(2,1,30),
(2,2,35),
(2,2,32),
(3,0,24),
(4,0,18),
(4,2,9),
(4,0,33),
(4,3,45),
(5,0,21)
SELECT * FROM ##TBL
```

How can i get the result bellow
for example when the ID are the same,then i should find the percentage of max PersonCount value.
eg where ID = 2 then PersonCount column will be  35/(30+35+32) that max value of PersonCount column divided by the sum(PersonCount)
and if is like ID= 5 then i should have 21/21 = 1.00

i should have this result

```
ID  NO  PersonCount Percent
0   0   36  0.78
2   2   35  0.36
3   0   24  1.00
4   3   45  0.43
5   0   21  1.00
```

Many thanks guys in advance
Any question please let me know

Comment: The result `NO` is `MAX(NO)` or `NO` for `max(PersonCount)` row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, MAX( NOs ) NOs, 
    MAX( PersonCount ) m, 
    CAST( CAST( MAX( PersonCount ) AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) /  CAST( SUM( PersonCount ) AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) x
FROM ##TBL
GROUP BY ID
```

I hope this isn't your homework!